# javascript stopped working after upgrading framework to .net 4.6

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.6

I have a simple javascript code that autotabs on textboxes. It's working for many years even on framework 3.5. When we upgrade the web server (hardware and software) to include VS 2017 and framework 4.6, the simple js autotab stopped working but does not have errors. I can't decipher the root cause although I'm sure it's related to the upgrade. Can somebody give me an idea as to what can cause this?

```
<td valign="middle">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function FocusNext(Cur, Next)
            {
            c=document.getElementById(Cur);
            if (c.value.length==c.maxLength) document.getElementById(Next).focus();
        }
    </script>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSSN1" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" size="3" MaxLength="3" onkeyup="javascript: FocusNext('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSSN1', 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSSN2');" TextMode="Password" />
    -
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSSN2" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" size="3" MaxLength="2" onkeyup="javascript: FocusNext('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSSN2', 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSSN3');" TextMode="Password" />
    -
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSSN3" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" size="4" onkeydown="return isNumberKey(event)" MaxLength="4" /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblssn" runat="server" CssClass="red" Visible="False" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:Label>
</td>
```

Comment: The version of .NET Framework doesn't affect the JavaScript at all, you must be looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: You should check the rendered IDs of the TextBoxes. An easy way to avoid the "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1"-type prefixes is to use `ClientIdMode="Static"`, in which case the ClientId is what you set the ID to. So you would use `FocusNext('txtSSN1', 'txtSSN2');`. If that works, then it is covered by the documentation for the [Control.ClientIDMode Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I very much appreciate it. I have tried your suggestion Andrew but remains unsolved.

Comment: @DennisR In that case, you will need to look in the browser's console to see if there are any relevant error messages. Press F12 in the browser and look around to find the "Console" tab.